# MonoGame XML IntermediateSerializer Interface and Initializers

Tags: c#, xml, monogame

I am terrible with figuring out how to name and explain my problems, so I apologize if this is confusing.

I want to be able use a class that implements an interface to create an instance of that interface. However, that interface doesn't (and shouldn't, as it may be useless to classes that implement/extend it) contain a certain property. However, for that class to do it's actual job, I need it to be able to properly "remember" or at least initialize itself before it's converted into the interface already.

Alright so simplified code what I'm trying to do:

Example Code:

```
public class DoStuff {
    public class DoStuffMethod() {
        //not sure if using an interface actually works, haven't tested that yet. 
        //I could probably just use another class and have the classes that were implementing IStuff extend such class instead. Although, not sure if that casts as well...
        IStuff stuff = Content.Load<IStuff>("Stuff");
        stuff.Initialize();
    }
}

public interface IStuff {
    int SomeInt { get; };

    void Initialize();
}

public class StuffClass : IStuff {
    public int SomeInt { get; private set; }
    public int SomeOtherInt { get; private set; }

    public void Initialize() {
        SomeInt += SomeOtherInt;
    }
}
```

Example Stuff.xml (as Stuff.xnb):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XnaContent>
  <Asset Type="StuffClass">
    <!-- Numbers have no significance, just random ones -->
    <SomeInt>1</SomeInt>
    <SomeOtherInt>4</SomeOtherInt>
  </Asset>
</XnaContent>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should be valid.

```
var obj = Content.Load<object>("your_xml_content_xnb");
if (obj is IStuff)
{
   (obj as IStuff).Initialize();
}
```